Cannot read the properties of Undefined (reading 'getContractFactory')
I've encountered this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContractFactory')

when I'm trying to run this script:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
    const newCode = await ethers.getContractFactory("simpleStorageRevision")
    // const newCode = await ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer)
    const contract = await newCode.deploy()
    console.log("Deploying contract, Please wait.....")
    await contract.deployed()
    console.log(`Deployed to: ${contract.address}`)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })


Are you having hardhat-ethers installed and listed in your dependencies or devDependencies inside package.json?

The error indicating that the ethers object doesn't have the getContractFactory method, It's likely due to how you're importing ethers from hardhat or how the packages installed.
1. Install ether.js 5.7.2 version:
Ensure ether.js is installed.
npm install ethers@5.7.2

2. Check ethers import: Ensure that you're importing ethers correctly, If you are using TypeScript, make sure that you're not mixing require and import statements. Use the appropriate import style.
3. Install the required packages:
Make sure hardhat is installed as a development dependency:
npm install --save-dev hardhat

4. Install required dependencies:
Install @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers for additional functionality
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers

5. Configure hardhat.config.js: Import necessary plugins:
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

Note: If you continue to face issues, please provide more details about hardhat.config.js and package.json file

@EddiePumpin update your body to add the hardhat.config.js and package.json files, so that i can see where exact issue is.

hardhat.config.js

Here is the link to the hardhat.config.js
https://vscode.dev/github/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/blob/main/hardhat.config.js
Here is the link to the package.json
https://vscode.dev/github/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc/blob/main/package.json


The first thing is you need to use this import: require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"); in your config.js file




Update the dependencies to this on package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^5.0.2",
"dotenv": "^16.4.5"
}


Make the config.js file like this :
equire('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");


const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
solidity: "0.7.3",
defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
networks: {
hardhat: {},
sepolia: {
url: API_URL,
accounts: [0x${PRIVATE_KEY}]
}
},
}
